# How do I include HTML in an onclick event inserted with Razor?

Tags: javascript, html, razor

I would like to insert an onclick event with Razor that opens a new window and writes html to it that is contained in a Model property.

Here is some code that works with a simple Hello World string:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.EmailDetails.Length; i++)
{
  var emailClick = "var wnd=window.open('about:blank','','_blank'); wnd.document.write('Hello World');";
  <small>
  <i class="fa fa-envelope" onclick="@emailClick" ></i>
  Some other text
  </small>
}
```

But if I try to insert some HTML instead:

```
<p class="h4">Hello World</p>
```

which renders as:

```
onclick="var wnd=window.open('about:blank','','_blank'); wnd.document.write('<p class="h4">Hello World</p>');"
```

or

```
<p class='h4'>Hello World</p>
```

which renders as:

```
onclick="var wnd=window.open('about:blank','','_blank'); wnd.document.write('<p class='h4'>Hello World</p>');"
```

neither is which can be work for obvious reasons.

Assuming I want to keep the html in a Model property, how can I get this to work... or is there another approach that will do it?

Comment: Here is a Fiddle of a simple case: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yvkpmv

Answer (score 0):

The problem is very simple: you should escape the attribute quotes mark for HTML markup because the JS code containing HTML markup is assigned inside C# code.

If you're using single quotes, the JS syntax error will occur because of unescaped single quote in HTML markup and you need to use double escape (`\\'`):

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

But if you're using double quotes, it will break C# string assignment statement because the string broken in 2 parts before and after `h4` (semicolon expected).

The correct usage should be like these:

**1) Using escape sequence**

```
// single quote
var emailClick = "var wnd=window.open('about:blank','','_blank'); wnd.document.write('<p class=\\'h4\\'>Hello World</p>');";

// double quotes
var emailClick = "var wnd=window.open('about:blank','','_blank'); wnd.document.write('<p class=\"h4\">Hello World</p>');";
```

**2) Using literal/verbatim string**

```
var emailClick = @"var wnd=window.open('about:blank','','_blank'); wnd.document.write('<p class=""h4"">Hello World</p>');";
```

**Update:**

Since the HTML string passed from string property and single quote used for `document.write` in JS code, just use `string.Replace()` to escape the quotes with `\\'` or `\"`, hence creating valid JS statement:

```
// single quote escape
var emailClick = "var wnd=window.open('about:blank','','_blank'); wnd.document.write('" + Model.EmailHtml.Replace("'", "\\'") + "');";

// double quote escape
var emailClick = "var wnd=window.open('about:blank','','_blank'); wnd.document.write('" + Model.EmailHtml.Replace("'", "\"") + "');";
```

Working example: [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pwJVgb)

Comment: This doesn't work for the approach I was taking.  Please look at https://dotnetfiddle.net/yvkpmv to see a very simplified version of what I'm attempting to do.  I'm starting to think I should inject some JS into the page that contains the HTML I want to display and then call that from onclick.

Comment: Injecting JS into a script tag to store the html to a variable works OK - https://dotnetfiddle.net/hAQ1zR

Comment: A simple `Replace()` works fine in my case, but not sure if that satisfy your requirement. The problem is you're passing string contained single quote into JS statement which uses single quote as in `document.write()` function.

Comment: That's right - quotes inside quotes inside quotes is the problem. Saving the html to a variable stored on the window object worked fine though - see Fiddle above.